# \lstlistoflistings causing error

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, listings, compiling

my problem is, I added some listings to my Tex document. On the first run everything went fine and all was shown. After the second rerun, it does not compile anymore.

Error:

```
 !Paragraph ended before \contentsline was complete. <to be read again> \par l.6 ...9.4169pt}\xdef 101.60083pt{101.60083pt}\par \noindent \hbox {}\global... I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

As soon as I delete the

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

to show the listings in the table of content, it does compile again.

I already deleted all captions from the listings. But it is still not working.

Every help is appreciated.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}    
% Use PNG graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% Listing
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

% Package for textcolors
\usepackage{color}

% picture captions
\usepackage{capt-of}

% create indexes
\makeindex
% Href
\usepackage{nameref}

% Colors for background of listing
\definecolor{myGrey}{gray}{0.9}
% Style of the listing
\lstset{
language=java,                      % Code language
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,    % Style
keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,  % Style for keywords
identifierstyle=\color{blue},       % Identifier get special color
stringstyle=\ttfamily,              % Stil of the Strings 
breaklines=true,            
numbers=left,               
numberstyle=\tiny,          
frame=single,               
backgroundcolor=\color{myGrey},     
caption={Java-Code},            % Caption
tabsize=2               
}



\begin{document}

% Main Page%
\include{latex_settings}
% show table of contents
\newpage
\tableofcontents
 %show all figures in table of content
 \listoffigures
 %show all listings in table of content
 \lstlistoflistings (**this caused the error**)
 %input other tex documents
 \input{tex}

 \printglossaries

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like you used a fragile command, delete the generated file with the listings probably delete all files except your tex source so .aux as well then try again.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this really did the job, should have thought about this.
Post your comment as answer, gonna mark it as solved asap. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @broesel001 It would be better if you added the offending caption.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did at a little MWE, hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you used a fragile command, delete the generated file with the listings probably delete all files except your tex source so `.aux` as well then try again.

If you put your captions back, prefix any fragile command with `\protect` so it does not expand at the wrong time while the external file is being written)